# Access "data" folder from another OpenShift application

Tags: php, node.js, openshift

I have an existing PHP app working on an Openshift application which is saving some files into the "DATA" directory.

Now I am migrate the same code to nodejs and I am putting it on another OpenShift application (in the same OpenShift account and domain).

What I would like to achieve is to **have the PHP application writing files to the "DATA" dir of the nodejs application** to keep existing and working PHP code running and creating files, but consuming those files from the nodejs app.

In the future I can plan to migrate existing and missing PHP code to nodejs as well.

Thank you!

Best regards,
Camillo

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to be possible. The DATA directory is local to the OpenShift gear. You can't even share a DATA directory between multiple gears of a single scaled application. You would probably be better off switching to a distributed file system such as [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) that both applications could access.